# The bottom border of the new topbar tabs is covered up by the next tab to the right

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

The line at the bottom of the current topbar item is cut off when hovering the one to the right to it:
[image: not hovered is on top; hovered is on bottom]
The culprit is this rule in the CSS:

```
.so-header .navigation .-item {
    margin-right: -1px
}
```

I don’t know why it’s there, but it seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: I've sat here for about 15 minutes trying different browsers and changing the CSS to see if anything broke or looked better.. but I actually can't find a reason. Tried adding padding, changing the margin to 1px, changing the Z index, but IMO it looks best at 0 (no css rule).

Comment: Pretty sharp eye you got there!

Comment: They put it there to see how long it would take before someone asked a question about it.

Comment: It took me an embarrassingly long time to figure out what you were talking about. Maybe a slightly less-zoomed-in picture would be helpful. (also, very good eye!)

Comment: It's the distinct lack of freehand circles that caused me to be confused about what the OP was saying...

Comment: Now that you have pointed this out I can not unsee it. Thanks for ruining the navbar for me.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/FDyLock.gif thanks a lot @OP, now I can't unsee it.

Comment: finally! a one-pixel-off problem that can be reproduced on more than two browsers. should stay in as a feature.

Comment: oh crap, this is definitely a bug. it's actually legacy from one of experiments we ran previously... i'm adding this to my todo list, should be fixed tomorrow morning.

Comment: fix coming in next build...

Comment: @Paweł Could you post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It was definitely a bug and it was actually legacy code from some previous experiments we ran.

It is now fixed. Thanks for reporting!